# How to for each new object push it into array, with avoiding override? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got a function, which calculates loan based on price, months and rate, then creates object of loan data.

```
let ratae = list.map((rata) => rata.NKS);
let prr = article.price;
let price = parseFloat(prr.replace(/\.| ?€$/g, '').replace(',', '.'));

for (i = 0; i < ratae.length; i++) {
  loan = new LoanJS.Loan(price, 2, ratae[i]);
  console.log(loan);
}
res.status(200).json(loan);
```

So problem is that loan overrides it's self every time new `ratae[i]` is fetched. `console.log(loan)` is looking like this:

```
{ installments:
   [ { capital: 162222.19,
       interest: 1113.13,
       installment: 163335.32,
       remain: 162777.81,
       interestSum: 1113.13 },
     { capital: 162777.81,
       interest: 557.51,
       installment: 163335.32,
       remain: 0,
       interestSum: 1670.64 } ],
  amount: 325000,
  interestSum: 1670.64,
  capitalSum: 325000,
  sum: 326670.64 }
{ installments:
   [ { capital: 162233.67,
       interest: 1067.08,
       installment: 163300.75,
       remain: 162766.33,
       interestSum: 1067.08 },
     { capital: 162766.33,
       interest: 534.42,
       installment: 163300.75,
       remain: 0,
       interestSum: 1601.5 } ],
  amount: 325000,
  interestSum: 1601.5,
  capitalSum: 325000,
  sum: 326601.5 }
```

So my response in postman will only be last `installments`.
I need some kind of loop, that for every new installments(or every new loan) pushes it in array/object, then my desired output would be:

```
{ installments:
   [ { capital: 162222.19,
       interest: 1113.13,
       installment: 163335.32,
       remain: 162777.81,
       interestSum: 1113.13 },
     { capital: 162777.81,
       interest: 557.51,
       installment: 163335.32,
       remain: 0,
       interestSum: 1670.64 } ],
  amount: 325000,
  interestSum: 1670.64,
  capitalSum: 325000,
  sum: 326670.64 }, //here to add comma or something else to create new object or array of installments
{ installments:
   [ { capital: 162233.67,
       interest: 1067.08,
       installment: 163300.75,
       remain: 162766.33,
       interestSum: 1067.08 },
     { capital: 162766.33,
       interest: 534.42,
       installment: 163300.75,
       remain: 0,
       interestSum: 1601.5 } ],
  amount: 325000,
  interestSum: 1601.5,
  capitalSum: 325000,
  sum: 326601.5 }
```

Also full function where this part is located in: https://jsfiddle.net/a5jk3fy7/
See it on jsfiddle, to prevent too much code on this post.

Any idea of solution? Thanks.

Comment: why not push each new installment simply in an array?

Comment: @Alex i've tried with some `array.push` variants, but nothing really worked. Do u have an idea how I would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const loan = list.map((rata) =>
     LoanJS.Loan(price, 2, rata.NKS)
);
```

Like the comment in your post, you are overriding `loan`. With this u map and for every `rata` u insert new entry of `loan`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like your problem could be due to the use of a global binding (`i`) as a counter in an asynchronous function (fetch).

If you declare `inside` your loop with `let i = 0` (similar to the simple example below), does the problem go away?

```js
let ratae = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < ratae.length; i++) {
  const loan = { detail: ratae[i] };
  console.log(loan);
}
```

Comment: yeah, this part of code is inside .then of promise.(I'm  using promise to query database to get `price`, `rates`. I've tried declaring `let i` and `const i` but nothing really changes. I've triend to add `{}` inside `new LoanJS.Loan({price, 2, ratae[i]})` but I get error. :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a5jk3fy7/ here u can see whole function with this part. Idea is to return tu user loan and article(article is easy to send).